# Issues With CMSIS In STM32IDE

Tags: stm32, hal, m4, cmsis

I'm completely new to microcontroller programming and I'm facing my first problem.
I'm following tutorials and web documentation in order to starting with STM32 libraries, I tried to add CMSIS and HAL drivers into my stm32IDE but every time I try to build a huge quantity of errors occure. Someone can explain to me what is wrong ?

```
../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32f412zx.s:399: Error: bad instruction `section .text:CODE:REORDER:NOROOT(1)'
../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32f412zx.s:400: Error: bad instruction `i2c2_ev_irqhandler'
../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32f412zx.s:403: Error: bad instruction `pubweak I2C2_ER_IRQHandler'
../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32f412zx.s:404: Error: bad instruction `section .text:CODE:REORDER:NOROOT(1)'
../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32f412zx.s:405: Error: bad instruction `i2c2_er_irqhandler'
../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32f412zx.s:408: Error: bad instruction `pubweak SPI1_IRQHandler'
../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32f412zx.s:409: 
.
.
.
.
make: *** [Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/subdir.mk:91: Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/iar/startup_stm32f407xx.o] Error 1
"make -j12 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

00:32:15 Build Failed. 5895 errors, 0 warnings. (took 2s.475ms)
```

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compile the IAR startup files with the GCC compiler.  The startup assembler file that you want is under the directory `gcc`.  The two assemblers have different syntax.

Comment: Hi, thank you to reply. I don’t if I understood, then I can exclude IAR from build and use only files inside GCC directory? Are the same files but for different compiler?

Comment: @Andrea you should start with an existing project (STMicro provides plenty of projects for the main compilers) and try to understand what files are included and why. it's not really obvious :)  Typically the startup functions are compiler specific that's why there is one file `startup_stm32xxx.s` for each supported toolchain.

Comment: @Guillaume Petitjean, thanks, I solved the problem by deleting the IAR and ARM and GCC folder. I use the startup file inside the STARTUP folder. In practice I think I don't need CSMIS but only the driver files inside the HAL library. At this point I don't know what the CMSIS library is for.

Comment: The HAL depends on the CMSIS.